# Bootstrap Modal With Canvas Does Not Display Responsive Design Correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, bootstrap-modal

In my Angular (not JS) App I'm using a bootstrap modal to provide a surface (HTML5 Canvas) where the user could draw up some sketches.

The problem I'm facing is that when I put the canvas inside the modal the responsive design suddenly stopps working:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modalbody">

    <other tags like buttons, inputs etc/>

    <canvas #canvas id="canvas"
            (touchstart)="touchDown($event)"
            (touchmove)="touchMove($event)"
            (touchend)="mouseUp()"
            (mousedown)="mouseDown($event)"
            (mousemove)="mouseMove($event)"
            (mouseup)="mouseUp()">
   </canvas>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
// Init Canvas Properties
@ViewChild('canvas') public canvas: ElementRef;
private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
private canvasElem: HTMLCanvasElement;

private setCanvasRenderingContext2d(): void {
    this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.canvasElem = this.canvas.nativeElement;
}
```

Before setting the canvasElem variable the modal displays responsive design correctly but as soon as I set it, the responsive design breaks and not only the canvas sticks out of the modal dialog but all other tags like buttons and inputs which are above the canvas (like a toolbox) also stick out.

The only thing canvasElem is used for is this here:

```
let rect = this.canvasElem.getBoundingClientRect();
```

otherwise I wouldn't even need it and the ctx variable is also only used for drawing operations, like ctx.fillRect and so on, so I'm really not sure whats wrong here..

Does anyone know of this issue and how do I solve it?

UPDATE:

My Solution/Hack is as Follows:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}, 1);
```

Width a delay of just a millisecond this works now perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be as simple as missing max-width css for your canvas.

```
canvas {  max-width: 100%; }
```

I did a simple jsfiddle to test it. without max width your canvas is not responsive. if you post a working snippet it's easier to reproduce.

https://jsfiddle.net/mzfk0qnt/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've just done another hack for this however: Since the grid system starts working after resizing the screen I just do this here:     setTimeout(() => {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    }, 1);